# How to replace XML File unicode characters in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, unicode, ms-word, ascii

The problem: A directory filled with XML Files containing "en dash", "em dash" must be replaced with a regular ASCII character dash. Also single/double left/right curly quotes which must be replaced with ASCII character straight single/double quotes.

Because of work limitations only VBA on a microsoft based computer can be used here (no access to powershell, scripting languages, java etc..)

I've learned VBA can interpret Unicode characters however it cannot write unicode characters. Instead of writing the unicode characters it replaces it with garbage (i.e. Ite$&s where "e$&" is garbage and output is supposed to be "It's")

An example I've attempted using string manipulation:

Pseudocode:

- Convert XML Content to String
- If Unicode Character "en dash" Is Found Then
- - Replace with ASCII Dash/Hyphen
- Write XML File

Example XML: (the first two dashes are en-dash and em-dash respectively not shown properly on stack overflow)

`<para> TEST REPLACE UNICODE CHARACTERS: — – - “ ” ‘ ’ '</para>`

Example VBA Output:

`<para> TEST REPLACE UNICODE CHARACTERS: â€" â€" - â€œ â€� â€˜ â€™ '</para>`

Code:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const TristateTrue = -1
Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim XMLString As String
XMLString = FSO.OpenTextFile(FilePath, ForReading, TristateTrue).ReadAll

UpdatedXMLString = Replace(XMLString, ChrW(8211), Chr(45))        'Replace En-Dash
UpdatedXMLString = Replace(UpdatedXMLString, ChrW(8212), Chr(45)) 'Replace Em-Dash
UpdatedXMLString = Replace(UpdatedXMLString, ChrW(8220), Chr(34)) 'Replace Left Double Curly
UpdatedXMLString = Replace(UpdatedXMLString, ChrW(8221), Chr(34)) 'Right Double Curly

Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objstream.Charset = "utf-8"
objstream.Open
objStream.WriteText UpdatedXMLString
objStream.SaveToFile UpdatedFilePath, 2
```

My Experience:

I know for a fact an En Dash exists in the file however a replacement of the character is unsuccessful. With Respect to the En/Em Dashes I do not enter the logic of the "If statement". However I do successfully enter the "If Statement" for Curly Quotes but replacement of the characters are unsuccessful.

Does the replacement of characters have to be performed prior to "FSO.OpenTextFile().ReadAll"? What is the appropriate code flow to replace Unicode characters with ASCII characters in an XML File?

Comment: Might help to show your complete code, including how you re-save the content.

Comment: Please add a minimal sample of XML file to your question. XSLT is the best way to handle your task.

Comment: Which quotes are you talking about, those in data in the XML e.g. inside element or attribute values? Or those that form part of the markup i.e. to delimit attribute values? Are those input files well-formed XML? You can run them through MSXML (New MXML2.DOMDocument60) perhaps, using XSLT 1, as already indicated in a previous comment.

Comment: @TimWilliams Added how I output the content to a new file.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Added a snippet of the XML

Comment: @MartinHonnen Quotes I am referring to are that of text output viewable from a users standpoint not XML syntax wrapping attribute values.

Comment: I'm not clear why you're trying to use VBA for this job. A text editor like NotePad++ can do find and replace operations on a folder full of XML files, and Unicode is not an issue. Or perhaps you can't even install a text editor?

Comment: @JohnKorchok that is correct, work computer limits software installation making things very tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a conceptual example for you.

The XSLT is using the `translate()` function.

- Each lower cased 'o' and 'i' will be translated/replaced with their
  corresponding capital letters.
- The input XML also has ***mdash*** as entity to make it visible. It is replaced
  by the XSLT with a regular dash.

For your case, you would need to put your own chars, and what they need to be replaced with.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
<!ENTITY mdash "&#8212;">
<!ENTITY ndash "&#8211;">
<!ELEMENT root (para)*>
<!ELEMENT para (#PCDATA)>
]>
<root>
    <para>Miami</para>
    <para>Orlando</para>
    <para>Dog &mdash; pony</para>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(., 'oi—', 'OI-')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <para>MIamI</para>
  <para>OrlandO</para>
  <para>DOg - pOny</para>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking up the suggestion to use XSLT here is a VBScript example you should be able to convert to VBA code that uses MSXML 6 to load an input document, to apply an XSLT stylesheet that `translate`s the relevant characters in text node and writes the result back to an XML file:

```
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xmlDoc.preserveWhitespace = True

xmlDoc.load "msxml-vb-input-sample1.xml"

Set xsltDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xsltDoc.load "msxml-vb-xslt-sample1.xsl"

Set resultDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")

xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xsltDoc, resultDoc

resultDoc.save "msxml-vb-xslt-result-sample1.xml"
```

The XSLT simply does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:param name="input-chars">—–-“”‘’'</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="output-chars">---""'''</xsl:param>
    
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="translate(., $input-chars, $output-chars)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and then transforms e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<para> TEST REPLACE UNICODE CHARACTERS: — – - “ ” ‘ ’ '</para>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<para> TEST REPLACE UNICODE CHARACTERS: - - - " " ' ' '</para>
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenTextFile has a `Format` argument you can provide to set UTF:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method#:~:text=TristateTrue,file%20as%20Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/opentextfile-method#:%7E:text=TristateTrue,file%20as%20Unicode).

If you do not provide that, it defaults to ASCII.

Also, I believe your original file may need to be saved as UTF-16

Comment: Updated code to reflect suggestion however it appears to not have any effect. Looked like a simple and promising solution though!

Comment: What's the encoding of your source (original) files?  Open one up in Notepad and go to Save As and check at the bottom of the dialog for the format.

Comment: It is UTF-8 but due to the destination for the XML it must remain UTF-8 @Tim Williams